# Filter a Gridview with a Combo Box Devexpress in mvc razor

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress-mvc

I would like to know if there is a way to filter a gridview using an HTML coded combo box? I am creating a web application using C# and MVC and I need some way to populate a gridview and allow the user to select something from a combo box and for it to filter the gridview.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the built in [Filter Builder](https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxGridViewDemos/Filtering/FilterBuilder) that DevExpress provides.

It is simple to apply:

```
settings.Settings.ShowFilterBar = GridViewStatusBarMode.Visible;
```

and therefore worth a look before going into more complicated methods.

The user can click on the filter string below the gridview. A popup appears that allows the user to build a filter by adding and removing criteria. This provides similar functionality to a checkbox, but with far less code.

Comment: In line with this answer https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_FilterExpressiontopic